# Float Right break on overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

How do you make floated elements stop floating on overflow? I'm trying to have something like this:

When the browser is fully maximized the two elements are meant to line up like this:

```
|span|                                  |span|
```

But when the browser re-sized to the point where the elements are touching this should happen:

```
|span|
|span|
```

I've tried doing it with floating like:

```html
<div class="border px-3">
   <span>December 6th, 2020</span>
   <span class="float-right">This is some example text right here</span>
</div>
```

But when I resize I get

```
|span|
           |span|
```

Comment: What you want can be done with flex. No floating rules.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want, but using `flex` rules. And exactly:

`display: flex` - sets flexibility;

`justify-content: space-between` - distributes blocks evenly throughout the free space;

`flex-wrap: wrap` - sets the transfer of blocks when narrowing the browser window.

```css
.border {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="border px-3">
   <span>December 6th, 2020</span>
   <span>This is some example text right here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some flexbox properties,

```
.my-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.first{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.second{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Corresponding HTML Code

```
<div class="my-container">
    <span class="first">December 6th, 2020</span>
    <span class="second">There is some example text here</span>
</div>
```